# a bar chart based on the total numbers for each year in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two columns in which there are different numbers in different rows for each year.

[image]

First, I need to display the sorted values based on the total numbers for each year.

Second, I need to create a bar chart in which, the y-axis in 'year' and each bar has a label which is the total number for that year.

I'm not sure if I explained the problem clearly, but I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us do

```
df.set_index('Year')['Goals scored'].sum(level=0).sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sum_by_years = (df.groupby('Year')['Goals scored'].sum()
   .sort_values(ascending=False)
)

sum_by_years.plot.barh()
```